# Using juju with maas worked at first but is now giving 503 error gomaasapi

Tags: juju, maas

I'm trying to add a unit:

```
juju add-unit myservice --to 6
ERROR cannot add unit 1/1 to service "myservice": cannot add unit to service "myservice": gomaasapi: got error back from server: 503 Service Unavailable (PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">

503 Service Unavailable

Service Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your
request due to maintenance downtime or capacity
problems. Please try again later.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at maas.jujugui.org Port 80

)
```

I'm guessing I need to restart some maas service, but which one?

Answer (score 3):

Someone (could have been me) had done something clever trying to proxy redirect web services using the same apache which is servicing maas.

This was in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled

### *This breaks /MAAS*

```
<VirtualHost *:80 > 
 ServerName example.com
 ServerAlias www.example.com

 ProxyPass / http://10.0.0.151:6543/
</VirtualHost >
```

Be sure to include a ProxyPass /MAAS ! directive BEFORE ALL of the proxy pass directives.

### *This allows MAAS to continue to work while proxying*

```
<VirtualHost *:80 > 
 ServerName example.com
 ServerAlias www.example.com

 ProxyPass /MAAS !
 ProxyPass / http://10.0.0.151:6543/
</VirtualHost >
```

So that the /MAAS urls are not proxied.